# How hide an element with respect to browser zoom

Tags: javascript, css, zooming

I want to hide a div if browser zoom is +200 or above.

The div which I wanted to hide is on right hand side of the site (absolute position, right 0px). So the idea is: if the browser zoom is default, then that div will be visible, but if browser zoom is more the default, then that div should not be visible to user.

Comment: Why do you need this? You are changing the expected behavior of zoom, which is to show the same content only larger

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers